# Android [Java] - how to instantiate a specific Bundle object

Tags: java, android, bundle, indoor-positioning-system

I'm developing an `Indoor Positioning System` app for a University project.
For this particular implementation, I'm using [Indoor Atlas' SDK](https://www.indooratlas.com/).
Everything works just fine, but - to make it more flexible - I would like to configure the API key and secret dynamically.
[As written on their docs](https://docs.indooratlas.com/android/latest/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/ialocationmanager) - to achieve this - I should instantiate the `IALocationManager` calling its own factory method `create` passing a Bundle object as a parameter called `extras` like so:

```
IALocationManager mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(mContext, mExtras);
```

But I still can't figure out how to instantiate `extras` to edit `EXTRA_API_KEY` and `EXTRA_API_SECRET` which are the `IALocationManager's` static attributes that I need to change.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Indoor Atlas service kindly responded to a mail I sent [answering my question with an example.](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/credentials/CredentialsFromCodeActivity.java)